# Type mismatch when utilising a case class in a package object

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am receiving the following error when I try to run my code:

```
Error:(104, 63) type mismatch;
found   : hydrant.spark.hydrant.spark.IPPortPair
required: hydrant.spark.(some other)hydrant.spark.IPPortPair
IPPortPair(it.getHeader.getDestinationIP, it.getHeader.getDestinationPort))
```

My code uses a case class defined in the package object spark to set up the IP/Port map for each connection.
The package object looks like this:

```
package object spark{
  case class IPPortPair(ip:Long,port:Long)
}
```

And the code using the package object like the below:

```
package hydrant.spark
import java.io.{File,PrintStream}
object identifyCustomers{
……………
def mapCustomers(suspectTraffic:RDD[Generic])={
    suspectTraffic.filter(
         it => !it.getHeader.isEmtpy
    ).map(
    it => IPPortPair(it.getHeader.getDestinationIP,it.getHeader.getDestinationPort)
)           ^`                                          
}
```

I am concious about the strange way that my packages are being displayed as the error makes it seem that I am in `hydrant.spark.hydrant.spark` which does  not exist.

I am also using Intellij if that makes a difference.

Comment: Could you post a complete code example which reproduces your problem? I tried it myself and could not reproduce your error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `sbt clean` (or the IntelliJ equivalent). You changed something in the project (e.g. Scala version) and this is how the incompatibility manifests.

Comment: I've seen this many times, and `sbt clean` always fixed it. I'd still be very interested in a deeper understanding of what goes wrong in this situation. Such a weird error!

Comment: seems to fix a lot, to be honest, i am using Maven but it helped a lot.

Comment: I had the issue again, there was something freaky going on in my local maven repo, just deleted and downloaded everything again!